# React equivalent for ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-ng-repeat, reactjs

I am new to React.js. I am trying to bind data arrays. I am looking for the equivalent of ng-repeat, but i can't find it inside documentation.

e.g:

```
var data =  ['red', 'green', 'blue']
```

using angular i would have done something like this in my html:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in data">{{i}}</div>
```

I am wondering the React's markup to do this

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In React, you just write the necessary JavaScript (and potentially build it into a reusable control as you'll see). It's very prescriptive and easy to do once you learn the basic patterns (and how they differ from AngularJS).

So, in the `render` function, you'd need to iterate through the list. In the example below, I've used `map`, but you could use other iterators as needed.

```
var List = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (<div>
        { this.props.data.map(function(item) {
                return <div>{item}</div>
            })
        }
        </div>);
    }
});

var data =  ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

React.render(<List data={ data }  />, document.body);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/kdcfx3sj/) it is in use.

And, as you can see, you can quickly build a reusable component that can "repeat" through the list.

Comment: Thanks can you please also explain the this.props.data.map to..?

Comment: @usama -- look for docs about `Array.map.` It's just returning a `<div>` for each item in the `data` array (as a new array).

Comment: Thanks @WiredPrairie

Answer (score 9):

Should just be:

```
{data.map(i => <div>{i}</div>)}
```

Comment: Do I need a library to convert that ES6 function so it can display in Chrome?

Comment: You should probably use Grunt or Gulp and a suitable ES6+ to ES5 transpiler with JSX support, such as Reactify (if you're using Browserify) or Babel.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example using ES6, and a stateless component.

The below code demonstrates creating a menu by looping through a list of menu items.

```
import React from 'react';
import Menu from 'material-ui/lib/menus/menu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/lib/menus/menu-item';


const menuItems = [
    {route: '/questions', text: 'Questions'},
    {route: '/jobs', text: 'Jobs'},
    {route: '/tags', text: 'Tags'},
    {route: '/users', text: 'Users'},
    {route: '/badges', text: 'Badges'}
    {route: '/questions/new', text: 'Ask Question'}

].map((item, index) => <MenuItem key={index} primaryText={item.text} value={item.route} />);


const Sidebar = ({history}) => (
    <Menu
        autoWidth={false}
        onItemTouchTap={(e, child) => history.push(child.props.value)}
    >
        {menuItems}
    </Menu>
);


export default Sidebar;
```

Basically what we're doing is just pure javascript iteration utilizing [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 1):

In your **render** function inside a react component you can do this:

```
var data =  ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
var dataComponent = [];
data.forEach(function (dataValue) {
    dataComponent.push(<div> {dataValue} </div>);
});
```

And now you can return the dataComponent.

Answer (score 0):

To perform the same task as ng-repeat in React you just need to think natively. Under the hood ng-repeat is just using a native Javascript iterator. You can use the same sort of native iterator directly in React. For example, I`ll use Array.map:

```
var RepeatModule = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { items: [] } 
  }, 
  render: function() {

    var listItems = this.props.items.map(function(item) {
      return (
        <li key={item.name}> 
          <a href={item.link}>{item.name}</a> 
        </li> 
      ); 
    }); 

    return (
      <div> 
        <ul> 
          {listItems} 
        </ul> 
      </div> 
    ); 
  } 
});
```

I got the above example from http://angulartoreact.com/ng-repeat-react-equivalent . The site has more examples of React equivaents to Angular directives.