# Can I replace ng-repeat in my mobile app with a React component?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

No matter what I try (`crosswalk`, `track by`, `collection-repeat`, `limitTo` with `infiniteScroll`, one-way binding, `ng-if`), using `ng-repeat` I'm not able to develop a good Ionic1 app.

Since React is a library, can I use a React component in my Ionic1 project instead a non-performant `ng-repeat`?

Which are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using [ngReact](https://github.com/ngReact/ngReact) and the equivalent of a `ng-repeat` as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994378/react-equivalent-for-ng-repeat)

```
var List = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (<div>
        { this.props.data.map(function(item) {
                return <div>{item}</div>
            })
        }
        </div>);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you mean when you said "not able to build good Ionic app"? I have experience with Ionic and that's quite nice framework I would say.
Is it slow or too complex or there is something else is wrong?
There is React Native if you want to use React.
If the problem only about ng-repeat I suggest to use [Ionic way of ng-repeat.](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `Ionic` is really great but that `ng-repeat` is defeating me. I want to do something similar to android's notifications: I have a list of elements, if I swipe one it should disappear and the other should move up to fill the empty space. Works great with 10 items, with 20/30 it lags also when scrolling.
P.S. it is slow with many items
P.P.S. It sounds really nice, but I can't rewrite my app now
P.P.P.S. `collection-repeat` seems to [not work for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251851/collection-repeat-with-angular-component-what-is-happening)

Comment: Are you using Crosswalk?

Comment: Yes. Everything works amazingly smoothly in the browser but fails on any real device :'(

Comment: On a real device it lags just a little bit, but it is not nice to use

Comment: Well, additionally I cam advise only (if possible) split your collection to the smaller parts. Or switch to NativeScript, that has better performance as I know.